# Accessing C struct members in inline assembly

Tags: c++, c, inline-assembly, masm

In the following code, `rEDX, rEBX, rEBP, rESI and rEDI` are the members of the structure `scratch_space`. `scratch_space_arg` is an object of the structure `scratch_space`.

```
lea eax, scratch_space_arg
mov [ecx+[eax].rEDX], edx
mov [ecx+[eax].rEBX], ebx
mov [ecx+[eax].rEBP], ebp
mov [ecx+[eax].rESI], esi
mov [ecx+[eax].rEDI], edi
```

This code gives me an:

```
error C2426: '[' : illegal operator in 'first operand'
```

for all the `mov` statements. Any idea how I can resolve this?

PS: I used [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fabdxz08.aspx) to access the `struct` members.

Comment: Have you tried `[ecx+eax].rEDX`?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend disassembling some C code that references the structure elements:

```
struct scratch_space scratch_space_arg = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int rEDX = scratch_space_arg.rEDX;
int rEBX = scratch_space_arg.rEBX;
int rEBP = scratch_space_arg.rEBP;
int rESI = scratch_space_arg.rESI;
int rEDI = scratch_space_arg.rEDI;
printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", rEDX, rEBX, rEBP, rESI, rEDI);
```

Then you'll know the correct notation to use yourself.

Comment: Have you tried this? I would expect the compiler to use hard-coded offsets, which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: I'd expect the compiler to use hard-coded offsets too...and the trick in part is getting those hard-coded offsets right. You can then go into the assembler and define the offsets as names — but you have to get the definitions right. If you don't know the hard-coded offset, you can't generate the correct assembler, can you? (It might depend on the power of the assembler you have available, of course. But Unix assemblers tend to be fairly bare-bones. MS Assemblers are probably more powerful. But you still have to know the offsets, somehow. The C compiler knows them; the assembler won't.)

Comment: The OP is using the inline assembler in the C compiler. So the structure definitions are available.